# What platform would you choose for Blackberry development?

Tags: c++, eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-jde

What platform would you choose for Blackberry development?

I can see several options, I'm kind of lost of how to begin

So far, I've seen the most popular is Black JDE, java sdk

I'm not looking for anything fancy, just some plain vanilla form based app.

what would you suggest?

Comment: It would be useful if people voting to close questions like these would actually bother to post a comment, indicating why they think this isn't a valid question, or what it would take to make the question *better*.  Although it certainly is difficult to consider any **one** answer to be **the** correct one here, questions like these are extremely valuable for developers, and I have a hard time rationalizing how **this** site isn't a good resource for finding people with the expertise to provide good answers.  I think the desire to prune certain kinds of questions is rather misguided.

Comment: I haven't voted to close this question but I can see the reasoning behind the 4 votes to close. The question leads to debate. I could for example, disagree with Remy on a number of points. One can program for the PlayBook in Java by using the Android runtime environment; I could ask for evidence that Eclipse is the more popular choice (I believe Remy is correct, but haven't seen evidence). There are other fora where discourse on opinion is not just welcome but encouraged. The FAQ is pretty clear that questions should be answerable base on evidence and facts, not opinions or personal choices.

Comment: I just don't understand why my account has to be locked because my question was closed

Comment: @Richard, I respectfully disagree.  First, what are these **number** of points with which you disagree with Remy?  Ok, the Android one is a stretch, as that only gives you access to a small fraction of BB devices, but I'll give you that.  Evidence regarding Eclipse? Really?  Does every *valid* SO question include **evidence** on every point in the answers?  Remy's answer is extremely objective, and fact-based.  If you have issues with a *part* of the answer, post a comment, like on every other answer on this site.  I don't want to shuttle between fora just because of this arbitrary filter.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that none of the 5 people who closed this question have significant SO points based on BlackBerry content.  The reason I personally am interested in this question is specifically because of how BlackBerry is different in this regard than other smartphone platforms.  With Android, or iOS, this really isn't a very interesting question.  With BlackBerry, especially given the pending BB10, it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Eclipse IDE is by far the most popular choice for Blackberry development.

Whether you want to code in Java or not is another matter.  You need to decide which Blackberry devices you want to develop for, because only current Blackberry smartphones use Java.  The Playbook tablet does not use Java, and upcoming Blackberry 10 smartphones will not use Java, either.  They use a mix of C++, WebWorks, and Adobe AIR instead.